# Как исправить ошибку в POST запросе

Tags: c#, post, steam, order

Хочу передать данные пост запросом к steam, но в ответ получаю ошибку, помогите разобраться:

```
 var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://steamcommunity.com/market/createbuyorder/");

        var postData = "sessionid=ххх";
        postData += "&appid=730";
        postData += "&currency=5";
        postData += "&market_hash_name=USP-S | Guardian (Field-Tested)";
        postData += "&price_total=1";
        postData += "&quantity=1";
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); // здесь выдает ошибку 400 Bad Request

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

А вот, что приходит в коде с сайта при выполнении вручную, куки не писал по понятным причинам:
General

Request URL: https://steamcommunity.com/market/createbuyorder/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 104.76.35.111:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://steamcommunity.com
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-NotLoggedIn
Access-Control-Max-Age: 604800
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 40
Content-Security-Policy: default-src blob: data: https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 19 Dec 2018 07:55:19 GMT
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Server: nginx
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Origin
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

Request Headers

Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 132
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie: 
Host: steamcommunity.com
Origin: https://steamcommunity.com
Referer: https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36

Formd Data

sessionid: 3b5608538832293729121e4c
currency: 5
appid: 730
market_hash_name: AK-47 | Redline (Field-Tested)
price_total: 100
quantity: 1

Comment: А откуда у вас тот адрес и данные для запроса? В браузере подсмотрели?

Comment: Да в браузере подсмотрел, когда вручную создавал, отследил код в браузере

Comment: Это хорошо, попробуйте указать больше заголовков. Мб дело в User-Agent, мб  в`X-Requested-With` если там через ajax было, мб нужно куки добавлять. Кст, ваша строка с postData очень похожа на параметры запроса, а не на данные формы. Точно не ошиблись?

Comment: Вам нужно по максимуму повторить запрос а это -- url с параметрами (если есть), заголовки запроса, тело запроса

Comment: `они не влезают в комментарий` ну комментарии не предназначены для такого. Добавьте лучше все это в вопрос (кнопка `править`)

Comment: Вообще такое лучше заворачивать в try/catch и ловить исключение. И уже в исключении смотреть, какой WebExceptionStatus. Так, сходу не скажешь в чём трабл.